# @copydoc for an enum class documentation

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am using @copydoc to distribute the documentation of an enum class to several places.
The log tells me that there is an error:

```
 /foo.h:19: warning: @copybrief or @copydoc target 'foo::Helper' not found
```

but the html output seems to be fine.

Are there any known bugs?

**Example**

```
/** @file
 *  @copyright xyz
 */

 namespace xyz {
 
 /**
  *  @addtogroup foo
  *  @{ */
 
 class foo {
 private:
 
     /**
      *  @brief Helper for enums
      */
     enum class Helper { one, two };
 
     /** @copydoc foo::Helper */
     enum class foo { three, four };

 };
 }
 
 /** @} */
```

Doxygen is V1.9.4 under Windows 10.
EXTRACT_PRIVATE is set to YES. All other settings are default.

Comment: You should add the doxygen version you are using and a the minimal code example that triggers this. The know bugs of doxygen can be found here https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: I get another warning as well: `aa.h:25: warning: unbalanced grouping commands` as the `/** @} */` is outside the namespace, it has to be placed inside the namespace as the opening is also inside the namespace.

Comment: Do you see the error as well?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue with 1.9.4 as well and I get the unbalanced grouping commands that @albert has, by moving the addtogroup command above the namespace both errors disappear. It might be a bug but for me it makes a bit sense that you have to define in which namespace the group you are working with exists.

Comment: Great. Thank you.
I've already corrected the namespace errors in my sources. Sadly I didn't look at the log file to confirm that the copydoc error has gone.